# How to execute queries on dynamic model, using only metadata?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm doing migration of legacy application to move from executing raw SQL to using ORM. The database design was that few entities, like Accounts, Transactions, Clients have corresponding tables with additonal fields (every client who bought our app - hosted always on-premise, have unique set of those fields), and those are made with columns (sigh). So for Transactions, you have table TransExt, and if customer of our app wants additional fields to be, for example, Description1 and Description2, table TransExt would have 3 columns, TransactionId, Description1, Description2. What I want is to effortlessly manage writing and reading them (only basic operations), abstracting the differences of our customer's database.

Since only 5 tables out of 40 aren't constant, it made sense to me to create one large DbContext and few smaller DbContexts with those changing-per-client tables in them, injecting small DbContext onto the big one. This would provide us with a easy way to change other table for all clients, and change those "dynamic" tables for each of them individually. I inject smaller DbContext onto main one, depending on app.config value with name of our customer, and it works fine. However, injectedContext has only the metadata (which makes total sense). How can I use them to run updates/reads?

Main DbContext has public property of injectedDbContext (in constructor). Nothing fancy there. Injected context is ClientExtContext. 
I can use them like

```
var db = new MainDbContext();
//db.constantTable //works
//db.ClientExtContext.TransExt //doesn't
var list = db.ClientExtContext.Model.GetEntityTypes().ToList()  //shows a list of object mapped to tables like TransExt, AccountsExt
list.ElementAt(7).GetProperties().ToList(); //gives me list of objects mapped to fields like Description1, Description2
```

What I want is to make operations on them. For example

```
var db = new MainDbContext();
var list = db.ClientExtContext.Model.GetEntityTypes().ToList()
var fieldsList = list.ElementAt(7).GetProperties().ToList();

list.where(s=>s.Name=="TransExt").Where(string.Format("{0} = {1}",fieldsList.ElementAt(0),someId) //this would give me TransExt row with someId, since fieldsList.ElementAt would point at column Id, using dynamic Linq
.Update(fieldsList.ElementAt(1), someDescription1Value); //first column which is Description1
db.SaveChanges();
```

Or better design, perhaps?

Comment: `string.Format("{0} = {1}"` appears to allow SQL Injection attacks.. yikes.

Comment: This is not SQL. It's dynamic LINQ there, to return object from list of objects. Also, this app is only used on intranet.